# How to keep a menu section expanded after having clicked?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, layout

My ASP.NET core app has a menu in _Layout.cshtml, with collapsible sections, but when I click on an item in a given section, this section collapses, and I would like to keep it expanded. But I don't know how to do, I thought to modify the bootstrap menu from the OnGet() razor method but I am reluctant to use javascript in a razor method. Isn't there a simpler method?

Here is my layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AppliPerso</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/AppliPerso.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }

        .glyphicon {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .panel-body {
            padding: 0px;
        }

            .panel-body table tr td {
                padding-left: 15px
            }

            .panel-body .table {
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }

        .container {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- menu-->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 leftMenu" style="position:sticky;top:20px">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">
                                    </span>Projet Euler
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-primary"></span><a href="Euler1">Problème n°1</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-primary"></span><a href="Euler2">Problème n°2</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                                    </span>Modules
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Orders</a> <span class="label label-success">$ 320</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Invoices</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Shipments</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Tex</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                                    </span>Account
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Change Password</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Notifications</a> <span class="label label-info">5</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Import/Export</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com" class="text-danger">
                                                Delete Account
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                                    </span>Reports
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Sales</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Customers</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Products</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Shopping Cart</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- page principale -->
            <div class="body-container col-sm-9 col-md-9 panel">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a page which uses this layout:

```
@page
@using Euler.MyFeature.Pages;
@model Euler.MyFeature.Pages.Euler1Model

<div class="row" style="background-color:red">
    <div class="col">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Résolution du projet Euler 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p> Voici la somme des entiers de 1 à 1000 qui sont divisibles par 3 ou 5:  @Model.sum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

EDIT
Hello Quing Gui, here is a short video which shows the menu collapsing after a click: [image]

have a good day

Comment: When you click the href will go to another website,what do you mean  "keep a menu section expanded after having clicked" ?

Comment: thx for your answer. I got the menu code from internet, and there some unwanted stuff inside it. For the moment, only the links to Euler1 and Euler2 are relevant. They point to two pages that have both _Layout.cshtml as their layout file. But if I am on the Euler page (which contains roughly only the menu), and I click on the Euler1 link (having the first menu group open necessarily), the Euler 1 page is well displayed, it contains the _Layout.cshtml menu, but now the menu it entirely collapsed, and I would like to keep the menu as it was before the click

Comment: Could you show it ? How  the menu it entirely collapsed ?And what you want it like in picture ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like below :  load external website in the view ?

Try to add below code in the layout, and change http to https
(like:https://www.jquery2dotnet.com):

```
<iframe id="content" src="" width="2000" height="3000">
            </iframe>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(" table tr td a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            var link = document.getElementById("content");
            link.setAttribute("src", page);
            $.get(page, function (html) {
                $('#content').html(html);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: hello, I changed my question with the content you asked for.

Comment: Hi @lolveley  , from your image, I think your method to show the content may reload the page,  so the menu it entirely collapsed. If you want to keep a menu section expanded , you can refer to my way to avoid reload the page .